# comunicación entre procesos

Tags: java

Buenas trades estoy teniendo problemas al comprender como funciona la comunicación entre procesos en Java. Quiero crear un proceso padre que le envie 10 numeros (del 1 al 10) a un proceso hijo y este realice la tabla de multiplicar con los mismos y le devuelva esa información al proceso padre para que la imprima por pantalla. 
Actualmente he realizado la prueba con un solo número.
El proceso padre

```
System.out.println("3");
```

Y el proceso hijo:

```
String texto;
        String tabla = "";
        String linea;

        int numero;
        int resultado;
         try {
            // TODO code application logic here

            Process hijo = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", "ProcesoHijo.jar" ).start();
             System.out.println("Proceso creado");

            BufferedReader entradaHijo = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(hijo.getInputStream()));
            PrintStream salidaHijo = new PrintStream(hijo.getOutputStream());

             System.out.println("El padre lee");

             texto = entradaHijo.readLine();
             numero = Integer.parseInt(texto);

             for(int i = 1; i<11; i++){
                 resultado = i * numero;
                 linea = (i+ " X " + numero + " = " + resultado+ "       "); 
                 tabla = tabla + linea;
             }
             System.out.println(tabla);



        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ProcesoPadre.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

Lo que no consigo es devolver la linea generada al padre para que sea este quien la imprima. Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente conseguí dar con el error.

El problema lo tenia con los flujos de entrada y salida del proceso hijo. La instrucción salidaHijo.println("Hola") es lo mismo que imprimir en el proceso hijo System.out.println("Hola"). De este modo se pueden mandar mensajes de un proceso a otro.